# How to set a timeout on a sync function in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to protect against users who create Liquid templates in our system that could cause a lot of processing (eg, infinite loop or very large loops).  I'm using LiquidJS.(https://github.com/harttle/liquidjs).

I currently have perl code that uses Template::Liquid and Sys::SigAction::timeout_call to accomplish calling the Liquid render function with a 100 ms timeout as follows:

```perl
use Template::Liquid;
use Sys::SigAction qw( timeout_call );
my $retval = "";
$data = {
  name => 'foo',
  title => 'bar'
};
my $template = 'Hi, {{name | upcase}} {{title}}!';
if ( timeout_call( 0.1 ,sub { $retval = Template::Liquid->parse($template)->render(%$data); } ) )
{
   print "Liquid template timed out\n" ;
}

print "retval=$retval";
```

Is there a NodeJS module that would help me accomplish the same thing in a similar code control flow?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is you can't easily put a timeout on a synchronous function call in node.js.  Because your Javascript is executed in a single-threaded event-driven system, while a synchronous call is running, no other events can get processed, including timers.

If you really wanted to protected yourself from this synchronous call, you would have to move it out of the main thread, either by putting it into a [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) or into a [WorkerThread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).  You could then have a timer in the main thread that, if it doesn't get a response before your timeout, you can kill the child or worker.

Now, if you control the code inside the synchronous call, you can code in your own protections within the synchronous call.  It could not the time at start of execution and multiple places during processing, it could check how much time has elapsed and then abort if too much time has passed.   But, this would have to be done from inside the code for the synchronous call, not from the outside and would typically involve checking the execution time during a loop or in some code that is regularly called as part of the operation.

Comment: Thank you! Curious if there a module that has a similar api to the perl equivalent that abstracts away worker implementation and I can just pass a function to execute with the timeout?

Comment: @AngularNerd - I'm not aware of any pre-built modules for that.  If you run the code in its own process using a synchronous child_process option, then there are timeout options built-in to those functions.  If you run it in a webWorker or asynchrononous child_process option, it's only a few lines of code to implement your own `setTimeout()` that kills the process/thread if it doesn't finish before the timeout.